# Attempt to invoke virtual method ' 'on a null object reference

Tags: java, android

I am getting the following error

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.StackView.setAdapter(android.widget.Adapter)' on a null
>   object reference

on this line

```
stackView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The complete fragment **EventsFragment.java** is

```
public class EventsFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    private StackView stackView;
    private  ArrayList<Stack_Items> list;
    TypedArray eventLogo ;
    String eventName[];

    @Nullable
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        eventLogo= getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.event_stack_icon);
        eventName = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.event_stack);
        stackView = (StackView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.stackView1);
        list = new ArrayList<Stack_Items>();

        //Adding items to the list
        for (int i = 0; i < eventLogo.length(); i++) {
            list.add(new Stack_Items(eventName[i], eventLogo.getResourceId(i,-1)));
        }
        //Calling adapter and setting it over stackView
        Stack_Adapter adapter = new Stack_Adapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), list );
        stackView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.events_layout, null);
    }
}
```

**Stack_Adapter.java**

```
public class Stack_Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<Stack_Items> arrayList;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    public Stack_Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Stack_Items> arrayList) {
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Stack_Items getItem(int pos) {
        return arrayList.get(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int pos) {
        return pos;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stack_layout, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        holder.text.setText(arrayList.get(pos).getName());
        holder.image.setBackgroundResource(arrayList.get(pos).getImage());

        return view;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;
        ImageView image;
    }

}
```

**Stack_Items**

```
public class Stack_Items {
    String name;
    Integer image;

    public Stack_Items(String name, Integer image) {
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;

    }

    public int getImage() {

        return image;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing:

```
stackView = (StackView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.stackView1);
```

Your `stackView` is `null`. `getActivity().findViewById` returns `null`.

Why are you using `getActivity()`?

Where is the `stackView`? You should load it from the right xml.

as @Tauqir mentioned, you need to inflate the right xml like this:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.events_layout, null);
stackView = (StackView) view.findViewById(R.id.stackView1);
return view;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside **onCreateView**

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.events_layout, null);

        -------------some codes ------------

        stackView = (StackView) view.findViewById(R.id.stackView1);

        -------------some codes ------------
        return view;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`R.id.stackView1` is not found when you try to assign `stackView`, so it is `null`

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.events, container, false);
stackView = (StackView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.stackView1);
.
.
.
return rootview
```

You first need to inflate the layout and call findViewById() on the View it returns, thus getActivity().findViewById should be rootView.findViewByID.

There are some other issues with your code as well. Like getctivity().getApplicationContext, just getActivity() is fine.

Answer (score 0):

change container and false to null

Do this:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.events, null);
```